# script / command to get IPs from list of hostnames and combine into a single file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, awk

This is beyond my current skills it seems as I've been trying for a while and not making much headway.

I've been asked to get a list of hosts and IPs for security to run a scan against those servers.  There is a hostlist named `hosts.linux` on the server with all the hostnames, just no IPs.  I'm trying to come up with a script that will take those names from that file and then run a command such as the `host` command to get the IP.

This command works for instance:

```
host csx-svc-spls-06 | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

and it returns just the IP of that server.  Is it possible to read from the file, have it run the command, and export the name of the server and then the IP address on one line to a new file?

Comment: How is the input file formatted? One name per line?

Comment: post a testable input fragment

Comment: Yes, it's one hostname per file, such as this:

Comment: abs-tzg-nbu-20
abx-bcn-app-d1
abx-bcn-app-t1
abx-bcn-app-t2
abx-bcn-app-t3
abx-bri-ora-t2
abx-bri-ora-t3
abx-bri-ora-t4
abx-bri-ora-t5
abx-cmc-dbr-t01
abx-cmc-dbr-t02
abx-cmc-dbt-t01
abx-cmc-dbt-t02
abx-cvs-ora-t5
abx-cvs-was-d01

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/424662/edit) with the updates, as you can see that the formatting in comments is limited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure of the implications of using nslookup over dig, but I think this might work:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do 
    nslookup "$i" | grep '^Name' -A1 | 
        awk '{print $2}' 
    echo
done < linux.hosts > outputfile
```

Comment: The command you provided worked.  Shows the hostname, with the IP on the next line.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help! Please, consider "accepting" this answer if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 8):

**`dig` has a `+short` option that makes it produce *only* the resulting IP addresses and nothing else.**

---

This code:

```
for h in google.com yahoo.com notfound.nosuch; do
  printf '%s = ' "$h"
  printf '%s' "$(dig +short "$h")" | tr '\n' ,
  echo
done
```

Produces the output:

```
google.com = 108.177.112.102,108.177.112.139,108.177.112.101,108.177.112.138,108.177.112.100,108.177.112.113
yahoo.com = 98.138.252.38,98.139.180.180,206.190.39.42
notfound.nosuch =
```

---

By contrast, this code:

```
for h in google.com yahoo.com notfound.nosuch; do
  printf "$h = %s\\n" $(dig +short "$h")
done
```

Produces the output:

```
google.com = 108.177.112.138
google.com = 108.177.112.100
google.com = 108.177.112.101
google.com = 108.177.112.113
google.com = 108.177.112.139
google.com = 108.177.112.102
yahoo.com = 98.139.180.180
yahoo.com = 206.190.39.42
yahoo.com = 98.138.252.38
notfound.nosuch =
```

---

To read the hostnames from a file, replace the `for` lines in either of the above code snippets with `for h in $(cat hostlist.txt); do` — although you may want to add some input validation.  Up to you.

---

Take your pick.  If you want another format, please comment.

---

Note: if *all* you want is the IP addresses and you don't care about having the hostnames included in the output, then *all* you need is:

```
dig +short $(cat hostlist.txt)
```

Bear in mind, though, that any hostnames that don't appear in DNS will be silently ignored with this command.

Answer (score 1):

To just iterate over the list with the command that you used on a single host (slightly modified to also include the hostname itself):

```
while read h; do
    host "$h" | awk '{ print $1, $3 }'
done <linux.hosts >outputfile.txt
```

This reads from `linux.hosts`, applies the `host` and `awk` commands on each entry in there, and saves the result to `outputfile.txt`.

Or, if you will, on one line:

```
while read h; do host "$h" | awk '{ print $1, $3 }'; done <linux.hosts >outputfile.txt
```

---

The following is a much more generic approach that takes hostname aliases and multiple IP addresses into account and produces one line of output for each line of input in the supplied file:

Given a list of hosts in `hostnames.txt`, such as

```
www.uu.se
www.kth.se
www.su.se
```

Then, given a short `awk` script (`script.awk`),

```
/^;/ || NF == 0 { next }

$4 == "CNAME"   { cn[$5] = (cn[$5] ? cn[$5] "," $1 : $1) }
$4 == "A"       { ip[$1] = (ip[$1] ? ip[$1] "," $5 : $5) }

END {
    for (i in ip) {
        if (cn[i])
            printf("%s (%s) = ", i, cn[i])
        else
            printf("%s = ", i)

        print ip[i]
    }
}
```

The `bash` command line

```
dig +noall +answer -f hostnames.txt | awk -f script.awk
```

would produce

```
su.se. (www.su.se.) = 193.11.30.171
www.kth.se. = 130.237.28.40
live.webb.uu.se. (www.uu.se.) = 130.238.7.135,130.238.7.133,130.238.7.134
```

This takes host name aliases and hosts with multiple IP addresses into account. The host name aliases are the names in parentheses.

The `dig` command by itself would produce the output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> www.uu.se +noall +answer
;; global options:  printcmd
www.uu.se.              300     IN      CNAME   live.webb.uu.se.
live.webb.uu.se.        300     IN      A       130.238.7.134
live.webb.uu.se.        300     IN      A       130.238.7.135
live.webb.uu.se.        300     IN      A       130.238.7.133
www.kth.se.             600     IN      A       130.237.28.40
www.su.se.              300     IN      CNAME   su.se.
su.se.                  300     IN      A       193.11.30.171
```

and it does to through a batch query (`-f`) on the list of hostnames.

This is what the `awk` code parses and summarizes.

The `awk` script detects the `CNAME` entries for host name aliases and saves a comma-separated list of aliases for each real hostname in the `cn` array, and does a similar operation to save the IP addresses in the `ip` array for each hostname.

The `END` block goes through the hostnames in the `ip` array and checks to see whether it has any aliases or not.  If it has, these are printed in parenthesis. Then the list of IP numbers are added to the end of the line.